# I have an mp3 audiobook on my Mac, and want to listen to it on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, ios, audiobook

I have an mp3 audiobook on my Mac, and I wanted to listen to it on my iPhone .

I plugged my iPhone in, and synced "Audiobooks" and selected the audiobook in the list, via iTunes on my Mac.

So, I presume it's now on my iPhone.
How do I listen to it?

There seem to be solutions, but either:

- they aren't vanilla (I don't want to download anything non-native), or
- they are for older OS versions (I'm on iOS 9 and El Capitan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the series of .mp3 files as audiobooks (as I had), it will show up in iBooks.

I didn't expect to find it there!